# "Downloading public symbols" while  debugging  MS Test on Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, tdd, mstest

I am using MS Test with Visual Studio 2010 to write unit Tests. When I debug a Test it shows a Message box as shown below

```
Title : Downloading public symbols
Message : System.XXXX.dll
```

Has anyone else faced this issue with MS Test on Visual Studio 2010?

This problem does not come when I run a test. Its only when I try to Debug a Test

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817223/disable-vs-downloading-public-symbols

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is probably trying to break at an exception that is thrown from the .NET framework code.

Either uncheck exception breaking in Debug => Exceptions or deactivate framework debugging in Tools => Options => Debugging => Enable Just My Code