# Disable VS' "downloading public symbols"

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, download

When I debug my ASP.NET webapp in VS2010, a dialog appears with the title "Downloading public symbols".

How do I instruct Visual Studio *not* to attempt this?

Comment: Still broken in VS2015: (A) the cancel button turns grey and takes 30 seconds to cancel, (B) it still does this even if all "Symbol file (.pdb) locations" are unchecked and "Only specified modules" is selected, and (C) it's trying to download symbols for DLLs built within my OWN solution (perhaps something to do with having published symbols on NuGet?)

Comment: **for vs2015** :  apply  Merav Kochavi Answer.   then  go  to  tools>option>debugging>symbols : **Check "Only Specificd Symbols"**  be sure that list is empty

Answer (score 120, accepted):

You can do this from the Symbols option page

- Tools → Options
- Go To Debugging → Symbols
- Uncheck all of the listed symbol file locations

Also you may want to disable "Enable .net framework source stepping" in Tools → Options → Debugging settings.

Comment: I unchecked the only location listed (Microsoft Symbol Servers), closed VS, re-opened it, and again debugged my webapp.  Again the dialog appears, just as before.  Is this abnormal?

Comment: @lance I'd make sure it was still unchecked but if it is then yes that's unusual.  Teh only other thing I can think of is to make sure that "Just My Code Debugging" is enabled.  If it still repros I would file a bug with http://connect.microsoft.com

Comment: The symbol server location checkbox *was* still unchecked when I re-opened VS.  Enabling "Tools > Options > Debugging > General > Enable Just My Code (Managed only)".  Many thanks.

Comment: this is not the answer, see @AareP below for the answer.

Comment: **for vs2015** :  apply  Merav Kochavi Answer.   then  go  to  tools>option>debugging>symbols : **Check "Only Specificd Symbols"**  be sure that list is empty

Answer (score 121):

Disable "Enable .net framework source stepping" in Tools → Options → Debugging settings.

Comment: Only thing that worked for me!! All other suggestions about un-checking symbol servers did not stop this behavior.

Comment: Having removed cached symbols as described above, and having unchecked the various symbol locations I had, I was still getting this issue, even with "Enable .NET framework source stepping" unticked and with "Enable Just My Code" ticked. The only thing that fixed it for me was to tick "Enable .NET framework source stepping" (which unticks "Enable Just My Code" automatically) and then reverting both of these options to their previous values again.

Comment: Search here: **Tools -> Options -> Debugging --> General**

Answer (score 25):

From VS Main Menu -> Debug -> Options and Settings
Make sure all the following parameters are configured as follows:

> 1. Debugging -> General -> **'Enable Just My Code' is Enabled**
> 2. Debugging -> General -> **'Enable .NET Framework source stepping' is Disabled**    (this might occur automatically after setting step 1)
> 3. Debugging -> Symbols -> **All symbol files locations are unchecked**