# Visual Studio 2010 hangs when debugging C

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging

So I'm just starting out with Visual Studio 2010, which is what they gave us at the university for our lessons in C language.

I wrote the simplest thing I could think of, just to test it out. It's a single printf command, naturally with the appropriate library included and a "main" function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() 
{
    printf("Hello world");
}
```

Compilation goes through just fine, but when I start the program without debugging it just shows me an empty screen. Debugging the program freezes VS altogether.

Asked my teacher and professor, asked my student peers, asked Google, and no proper answer so far. I've tried reinstalling Visual Studio twice.

Does anyone have a clue as to what's going on?

Comment: It might be a simple application - but please share with us your code - even if it is just a "Hello World" example you are attempting to run

Comment: VS doesn't usually "freeze" debugging "Hello, World!" type of application. May be your installation is corrupted? Also, why would anyone use VS2010 when the superior version of VS2013 (and VS2015) Community Edition is free?

Comment: It is a "Hello World", and the installation is fine. I even reinstalled twice to make sure.
Here's my code:
    `#include <stdio.h>  
void main()  
{  
 printf("Hello world");  
   
}`

Answer (score 0):

If may be attempting to download public symbol files. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817223/disable-vs-downloading-public-symbols) to see how to disable this.